# Unusual error in Clients website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I just created an account on my client's website (which I build for him). I have tested this website extensively and could not find any problems - 2 years ago. I've since tested it to make sure it's all running smoothly every month since the website was released.

I just created a new account on his website just now, and I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: <me@myemail.com> No such user here 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: <me@myemail.com> No such user here

Source Error: 



Line 62:                         HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token));
Line 63: 
Line 64:                     WebMail.Send(
Line 65:                         email,
Line 66:                         "Please confirm your Account.",


 Source File:  d:\HostingSpaces\website\website.com.au\wwwroot\Protected\Account\Register.cshtml    Line:  64 

Stack Trace: 



[SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: <me@myemail.com> No such user here]
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) +1229659
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1772
   System.Web.Helpers.WebMail.Send(String to, String subject, String body, String from, String cc, IEnumerable`1 filesToAttach, Boolean isBodyHtml, IEnumerable`1 additionalHeaders, String bcc, String contentEncoding, String headerEncoding, String priority, String replyTo) +686
   ASP._Page_Protected_Account_Register_cshtml.Execute() in d:\HostingSpaces\website\website.com.au\wwwroot\Protected\Account\Register.cshtml:64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +208
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +68
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +123
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +67
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +121




Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

What the??? The email address listed down there is the email address I used to create the account. After getting this error, I then logged into that email account online - and it's there - with all my mails. So the user does exist. So then why does WebPages framework thing that this user does not exist when trying to send an email confirmation to it?

The email variable you see up there in the code - it's value is listed in the exception itself.

Comment: Mailbox full?  Account disabled?

Comment: @DStanley neither. +1 for trying though :)

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that for a fraction of second the mailbox was unavailable for some reasons. try again creating the account and it should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem for the client. I can't really tell them to tell their customers to "try again". Also, these exceptions are becoming more frequent.

Comment: @jAsOn I agree. Are the emails being used from public email providers (gmail/yahoo) or company's personal accounts? if tyhey are from company's accounts, something can be derived from the logs!

Comment: thanks for getting back. It's from company accounts. Not sure where to look for logs though

Comment: Hmm..Look for some logs in your mail server or contact your system admin whether the mail server is being down for a fraction of second or something similar.